# Neo4j CSV Import Execution Failure

Tags: csv, neo4j

I'm trying to import a CSV file into Neo4j (Community Edition V 2.3.3). The Error is  Neo.DatabaseError.Statement.ExecutionFailure
And it shows like this:

```
    At O:\Sample1.csv:132851 -  there's a field starting with a quote and whereas it ends that quote there seems to be characters in that field after that ending quote. That isn't supported. This is what I read: 'MQP Coverage EPG"'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input file has a string with an un-escaped quote in it. Find and fix that and you'll be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your CSV data has another quote character than the default `"`. You seem to have `'`, is that correct? If so then add the argument `--quote '` to the import tool command.